# How to solve the recurrence with two variables?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

$M$  is also a variable. 
\begin{equation}
    T(n)=
    \begin{cases}
      16T(n/2)+\theta(1), & \text{if}\ n^2> M \\
      M, & \text{if}\ n^2\le M \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? Have you tried the substitution method?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and if you still can't solve it, edit the question to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I solved it by the substitution method.